# Whats the difference between these two?

Tags: fluid-simulation

[![enter image description here][1]][1]what is the difference between these 2 ? can you please sepcify

and how to convert the atoms one diagram to the solid form one, can you please tell the steps?

i am a total beginner so dont mind as i have searched many places but i cant understand

thank you[image]

[image]

File: [image]

Comment: Select you domain and in the Physics panel > Liquid > enable the Mesh option

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On the first picture the fluid is displayed as particles, on the second it is displayed as mesh, to display as mesh, go in the *Properties panel > Physics > Liquid*, and enable the *Mesh* option:

[image]

Comment: i have ticked both of the options but when i baked it again it dosn't transformed to the mesh one, what to do

Comment: what do you mean by mesh 1? Maybe share your file (only keep the minimum): https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/

Comment: please see the 1st image

Comment: could you please share your file? I'm not expert enough on physics so I can't guess

Comment: done! please help me

Comment: you need to copy paste the link (read the instructions): https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/

Comment: [<img src="https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/embedImage.png?bid=KGEg29px" />](https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/b/KGEg29px/)

Comment: maybe try that: activate Mesh, then in the Cache, swtich from Modular to All, choose Frame Start 1 and End 30 to make it short, click on Bake All, then test

Comment: yep its blue and looking like a mesh thanks